# which papers consider entry of buyers or consumers in a Salop (1979) circle?

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request

I am considering a platform shaped like a Salop circle where sellers and buyers interact. I want to study free entry of buyers which amounts to an increase of the length of the circle or an increase in the density of buyers. I cannot find literature where this is the case (only literature about seller entry).

Comment: Are there any economics papers (not just Salop models) that explicitly model buyer entry? I mean not as an exogenous process, but as a decision, if I understand what you mean.